# SQL data is not loading

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, express

Does anyone know why my request just gets stuck loading when trying to access my database ?
My database name is test. If set the database: books or something like that for example. Then it returns the error database is unknown: books so I assume that my password is correct it just isn't finding the test data base ?

```js
// To import these packages remember to add "type":"module" to package Json
import express from "express";
import mysql from "mysql";

const app = express();

const db = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "keks000207",
  database: "test",
});

// This is an API request with an Express server
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.json("Hello this is the backend");
});

app.get("/books", (req, res) => {
  const q = "SELECT * FROM books";
  db.query(q, (err, data) => {
    if (err) return res.json(err);
    return data;
  });
});

app.listen(8800, () => {
  console.log("Connected to backend!");
});
```

Comment: you should query databases asynchron see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47213089/querying-a-database-in-node-js-asynchronously

Answer (score 0):

Try `db.connect()` or similar method available in the file itself.

And Instead of `return data` inside the callback of `db.query`, you should use `res.send(data)`, then you will get the response in the `GET /books API`.